# How do I print a binary number's digits individually Python?

Tags: python, binary

I am trying to understand how to print off a binary numbers digits individually. For example, if the binary number is 1011, I want to print to the console:

1

0

1

1

I am basically going to assign these numbers individually to different GPIO pins of a Pi.

Comment: Which version of python you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one:

```
number = str(1011)
for i in number:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
bin=str(1011)
def print_to_console(agg, item):
  print(f'{item}\n')

reduce(print_to_console, bin, bin[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are storing binary number in variable, its as simple as this

```
a = 11000
for i in str(a):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
1
1
0
0
0
```

but if wont print the left most zeros, i.e. if num is 00100, the above code will print 1,0 and 0.
To not lose left most zeros, store binary digit as a string.

```
a = "0100"
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
0
1
0
0
```